# Codeigniter - passing form input information to the controller and displaying it on next view

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, post, view, controller

This question is possibly a duplicate but I cannot find the exact answer I am looking for.

I have two forms and two controllers.

I want to input data into the fist controllers view. on that page submit the data tot he second controller and display it on that controllers view.

Now I have tried to insert the form input data in an array in my controller and then access it as a normal variable in the view but without luck.

**My Controller for first form**

```
function new_order_details() 
  {
      $this->load->view('sales/new_order_details');
  }
```

**My input form view: new_order_details'**

```
<form id="sales_order_details" action="/sales/new_blank_order_lines" method="post">
<input type="text" id="customer" />
<input type="submit" name="blank_order" id="blank_order" value="Continue">
</form>
```

**My Controller for second form**

```
function new_blank_order_lines() 
  {
     $data = array(
    'customer' =>$this->input->post('customer')
       );
      $this->load->view('sales/new_blank_order_lines',$data);
  }
```

**and my view where I want to display data**

```
<?php echo "--".$customer."--"; ?>
```

The output of the above is that the variable $customer is empty.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is empty because you have not given name parameter to customer input field in view file.

Write html as below

```
<input type="text" id="customer" name="customer" />
```

Comment: perfect answer! +1 :) Made my day!!!

Answer (score 1):

your are missing name attr there for your input..

```
<input type="text" id="customer" name="customer"/>
                            //----^^^^^^^----- here
```

the value is then posted with the name you provided to the controller